# Check if a PHP cookie exists and if not set its value

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am working on a multilingual site so I tried this approach:

```
echo $_COOKIE["lg"];
if (!isset($_COOKIE["lg"]))
    setcookie("lg", "ro");
echo $_COOKIE["lg"];
```

The idea is that if the client doesn't have an `lg` cookie (it is, therefore, the first time they've visited this site) then set a cookie `lg = ro` for that user.

Everything works fine except that if I enter this page for the first time, the first and second `echo` return nothing. Only if I refresh the page is the cookie set and then both `echo` print the "ro" string I am expecting.

How can I set this cookie in order to see its value from the second `echo` on the first visit/page load of the user? Should be without needing to refresh the page or create a redirect.

Comment: I'd separate the need for client-side cookie (i.e. the $_COOKIE[] array) from a server-side session cookie - the $_SESSION[] array.  For further internal use in the code, use the $_SESSION cookie - it is accessible at once after setting.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

### Answer

You can't according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/setcookie):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

This is because cookies are sent in response headers to the browser and the browser must then send them back with the next request. This is why they are only available on the second page load.

### Work around

But you can work around it by also setting `$_COOKIE` when you call `setcookie()`:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lg'])) {
    setcookie('lg', 'ro');
    $_COOKIE['lg'] = 'ro';
}
echo $_COOKIE['lg'];
```

Comment: I would personally recommend against setting `$_COOKIE[]` value. This can trick some other piece of code later that the user did have this cookie. Alternative would be `$lg = (isset($_COOKIE['lg']) ? $_COOKIE['lg'] : 'ro'; echo $lg;`

Comment: Hi Ramy, i hope you been well i now that code was from 5 years ago .but can you be more clear i got invalid syntax as well...

Answer (score 17):

Cookies are *only* sent at the time of the request, and therefore cannot be retrieved as soon as it is assigned (only available after reloading).

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.
>
> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE. If setcookie() *successfully runs*, it will return TRUE. This *does **not** indicate whether the user accepted the cookie*.
>
> **Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page** that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cookie with php `setcookie` you `can see the set and the value` of the cookie, as an example, with the `developer tools` of firefox `just in time`.

`But you need to reload/load` the same/next `page` if you wanna read, get or check the cookie and the value inside `to work with that cookie` in `PHP`.

With this example you can `choose` if you wanna `reload` the same page with `PHP`, `HTML` or `JAVASCRIPT`.

If the cookie is not accepted or cookies are disabled, a loading loop is obtained and the browser stops loading the page.

**`LONGVERSION WITH PHP 'header' RELOAD SAME PAGE`**:

```
<?php

$COOKIE_SET     = [
     'expires'  => '0'
    ,'path'     => '/'
//  ,'domain'   => 'DOMAIN'
    ,'secure'   => 'true'
    ,'httponly' => 'true'
//  ,'samesite' => 'Strict'
    ];
    
$COOKIE_NAME    = "MYCOOKIE";
$COOKIE_VALUE   = "STACKOVERFLOW";
    
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_NAME])){
    setcookie($COOKIE_NAME, $COOKIE_VALUE, $COOKIE_SET);
    // YOU NEED TO RELOAD THE PAGE ONCE
    // WITH PHP, HTML, OR JAVASCRIPT
    // UNCOMMENT YOUR CHOICE
    
    // echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/">';
    // echo '<script>window.location.replace("/");</script>';
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
  }
else{
    echo ($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_NAME]);
}
  
?>
```

**`SHORTVERSION WITH PHP 'header' RELOAD SAME PAGE`**:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE'])){
    setcookie('MYCOOKIE', 'STACKOVERFLOW');
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

echo ($_COOKIE['MYCOOKIE']);
```