# problems with setting a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

hi in my code if there is no cookie show a page who set the cookie so the next time the user reaches the page will show another

```
if ((!isset($_COOKIE['app']) )){
        $plantilla->app_li();
        $val='desktop';
        $val1='app';
    echo setcookie($val1, $val, time() + (86400 * 2), '/');
    }else{
        echo $plantilla->home();
    }
```

if the cookie "app" exists shows $plantilla->home(); ,if not will show $plantilla->app_li(); and creat the cookie

but it dont create

Answer (score 0):

Use $_COOKIE to retrieve a cookie with PHP. Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load.

```
$val1='app';

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$val1])) {
        $plantilla->app_li();
        $val='desktop';            
    echo setcookie($val1, $val, time() + (86400 * 2), '/');
} else {
   echo $plantilla->home();
}
```

Looking your question and answer this link http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript

Comment: $cookie_name = 'pontikis_net_php_cookie';
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" does not exist...';
} else {
  print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" value is: ' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}

Comment: tyr this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738593/check-if-a-php-cookie-exist-and-if-not-set-him-a-value