# How To Get Cookie's Name In PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to get cookie's name in PHP. Not cookie's value! My code like below:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
$timing_clock = "";

if(isset($_COOKIE["timing_type"])){
  // cookie's value  
  $timing_clock = setcookie("timing_type");
 // how to get cookie's name?
} else {
   echo("0");
}
?>
```

How can i do that? I want to set cookie's name to a variable. Because cookie's name are very important for me.

Comment: Try to var_dump the cookies with `var_dump($_COOKIE);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a PHP cookie exists and if not set its value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738593/check-if-a-php-cookie-exists-and-if-not-set-its-value)

Answer (score 6):

it  will  help you, use `var_dump($_COOKIE)` and get all COOKIE name.

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Dave";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
if(isset($_COOKIE)) {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    foreach($_COOKIE as  $key => $val)
    {
      echo "cookie name = ".$key.", and value = ".$val;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i set this value to variable?

Answer (score 1):

This will print all with respective name

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_COOKIE); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example

```
setcookie("timing_type");
```

the cookie name would be **$_COOKIE['timing_type']**

When you use the setcookie function you are applying the cookie name(key).

Answer (score 0):

All cookies names are stored in `$_COOKIE` as `"Name" => "value"`.
Simply output the keys of the `$_COOKIE` array and you'll have your names :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply read `$_COOKIE["name"]` to get the name set by setcookie

Answer (score 0):

The first paramater of setcookie() is the name of the cookie

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
$timing_clock = "";

if(isset($_COOKIE["timing_type"])){
  // cookie's value  
  $timing_clock = setcookie("timing_type");
  // how to get cookie's name?
  $cookie_name = $_COOKIE['timing_type'];

} else {
   echo("0");
}
?>
```