# Not able to set cookies from form with php

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

I have checked the code many times, yet not able to find the error! the issetCookie returns false here.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <?php if(!isset($_REQUEST['sub'])) { ?>
   <form name="f1" action="1.php" method="post">
     Name : <input type="text" name="na"><br>
     Last Name : <input type="text" name="lna"><br>
     Email Id : <input type="text" name="eml"><br>
     Phone No : <input type="text" name="phn"><br>
     City : <input type="text" name="cty"><br>
     <input type="Submit" name="sub" value="ok"><input type="Reset" name="res" value="Clear">
  <?php } else {
     $name=$_REQUEST['na'];
     $lname=$_REQUEST['lna'];
     $email=$_REQUEST['eml'];
     $phone=$_REQUEST['phn'];
     $city=$_REQUEST['cty'];

     setcookie("Name", $name, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
     setcookie("LName",$lname);
     setcookie("Email",$email);
     setcookie("Phone",$phone);
     setcookie("City",$city);
  } ?>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me to **assign variables to cookie**?
If its the issue of else, please suggest alternate options of assigning cookie value using form data and retrieving on the next page defined in form action.

Comment: Where is `issetCookie()`?

Comment: The cookies with no expire time are session cookies, they go away when you close the browser.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting/18936052#18936052

Comment: You cannot output anything before setcookie(). It will cause `header already sent` error and setting cookie will fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get Cookie's Name In PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620317/how-to-get-cookies-name-in-php)

Comment: So the isset is on the next page i.e 1.php1                                 `<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{
  if( isset($_COOKIE["Name"]))
            echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["Name"] . "<br />";
else
 echo "Sorry";
}
?>
<a href=2.php> Show details </a>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @SakshiDeshpande did you tried given answer

Comment: yeah! @RahulShrivastava Still False for isset($_COOKIE) on 1.php

Comment: @SakshiDeshpande i updated the answer you are doing wrong try like that

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to set cookies in `else`  condition.so variables are not exist in else condition because form is not submitted. and you need to add expire time like this.

```
setcookie("Name", $name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");// one day
```

and check like this

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['Name'])) {
         echo "Cookie named  is not set!";
    } else {
         echo "Cookie  is set!<br>";
         echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['Name'];
    }
```

your code should be like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $name=$_POST['na'];
    $lname=$_POST['lna'];
    $email=$_POST['eml'];
    $phone=$_POST['phn'];
    $city=$_POST['cty'];
    setcookie("Name", $name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['Name'])) {
     echo "Cookie named  is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie  is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['Name'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
     <form name="f1" action="1.php" method="post">
     Name : <input type="text" name="na"><br>
     Last Name : <input type="text" name="lna"><br>
     Email Id : <input type="text" name="eml"><br>
     Phone No : <input type="text" name="phn"><br>
     City : <input type="text" name="cty"><br>
     <input type="Submit" name="sub" value="ok"><input type="Reset" 
     name="res" 
     value="Clear">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: refresh page again

Comment: you are trying to set cookies in else condition which is not correct

Comment: because when you submit the form values are exist but not in else condition

Comment: i am trying with javascript to set cookies. so that i need not use if...else

Comment: values  are not exist in else condition

Comment: when you will submit the form if (isset($_POST['sub'])) { will check form is submitted or not.if submitted values will active.otherwise values will not active.you are trying to set cookies when values is not active

Comment: it still shows Cookie named not set,(tried your code) I am a beginner and still struck at a single problem.

Comment: @sakshi i tested it

Comment: Refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

use like this.

```
$cookie_name = "name";
$cookie_value = $_REQUEST['na'];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```