# Capturing client IP addresses from the Google Maps API

Tags: php, apache, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to the Google Maps API (and KML processing in general); I have a set up on my website where I display a KML on my web server using the Google Maps API. I want to capture **all** client IP addresses that try to access our KML files, but noticed that the Apache logs "missed" some of the client IP addresses. To that end I've set up an `htaccess` script that captures the client IP:

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !fla=[^;]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ access.php?url=https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

If the "fla" cookie is not set, the `.htaccess` script directs all traffic to a PHP script in the same directory, `access.php`, that writes the IP address to a text file, sets an "fla" cookie to prevent an infinite loop, and sends the traffic to the intended destination (in this case, the KML file):

**`access.php`**

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('ips.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n");
    fclose($file);

    setcookie("fla", hash("sha512", random_bytes(10)), time() + 30, "", "", 1);
    header("Location: ". $_GET['url']);
?>
```

However, in my testing, I've noticed that while the file captures IP addresses when a client machine tries to access the KML file directly, the IP address belonging to the Google Maps API is only captured when the KML is first being resolved. All subsequent attempts result in the KML file loading on the page, but the source IP (from Google) is not being captured in the text file - the KML filename has to be renamed before the IP address is captured again.

Is there another way to capture **all** IP addresses coming from Google when the Maps API resolves the requested KML file?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1: After discussion in the comments below this post, I consolidated all the processing into one PHP file (calling it `servefile.php`), added some checks for `X-Forwarded-For`, and got rid of both `access.php` and the `.htaccess` file as they are no longer necessary:

**`servefile.php`**

```
<?php
    header("X-Frame-Options: deny");
    header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
    header("Strict-Transport-Security: Max-Age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");

    $ip_file = fopen('ips.txt', 'a+');
    
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER)) {
        $ip_addr = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
        $x_fwd_ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        $x_fwd_ips = array_map('trim', $x_fwd_ips);
        $ip_addr = $x_fwd_ips[0];
    } else {
        $ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    fwrite($ip_file, $ip_addr . "\n");
    fclose($ip_file);

    // redacted for security reasons; it is present in the live code
    $base_url = "";

    $file = $base_url . "" . $_GET['url'];
    $filename = $_GET['url'];

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
?>
```

Despite the reduced overhead, the IP address situation remains the same as before: the IP addresses are captured in the `ips.txt` file when a client tries to access the file directly, but when loading the Google Map the IP address is only captured when the KML is *first loaded*.

Comment: It seems the KML ([Keyhole Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language)) file is cached in the browser. You can give it [an header that it shouldn't be cached](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/http-caching-basics/), and hope the browser obeys. Your technique to get the IP address is somewhat complicated. Why not combine everything, including the KML into one PHP file?

Comment: Thanks! In previous fix attempts I tried adding `"no-cache"` to the `.htaccess` file to prevent caching, but that didn't appear to work; the Google IPs were still not being "captured" after first load. Your second question is interesting; do you mean something like have the PHP file serve the KML directly instead of using headers?

Comment: _"the Apache logs "missed" some of the client IP addresses"_  What does this mean? Do you have the server behind a load balancer or proxy? You might need to capture `X-Forwarded-For` instead.

Comment: PHP can [set and check cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738593/check-if-a-php-cookie-exists-and-if-not-set-its-value), it can [set no-cache headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site), and it can, obviously, serve KML code, so why not do all that in a PHP file?

Comment: It might be that Google buffers the KML, and not the browser. I am not familiar with this Google stuff, but I did find that [data is loaded only once by Links into Google Earth](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/expiration). Persumably the same is true for Google Maps? Perhaps the link is helpful? Another way to make some software think that they're dealing with other data is adding unique URL parameters. First: `servefile.php?ID=1234` and next `servefile.php?ID=1235`, and so on.

Comment: I added the unique URL parameters, but still no luck; in fact, it's gotten worse as now the KML doesn't render on the Google Map at all (it still works when you try to access the KML file directly, though).

Comment: _"sets an "fla" cookie to prevent an infinite loop"_ - to fail catastrophically, if the client doesn't accept cookies/this cookie, is what you meant to say here, right ...?